# Characterizing centralizer of nilpotent self-maps

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids

Let $\mathcal{C}_n$ be the monoid of self-maps $\alpha$ of $\{1\dots,n\}$ that are order-preserving ($\forall x,y$, $x\le y$ $\Rightarrow$ $\alpha(x)\le\alpha(y)$ and decreasing ($\forall x$, $\alpha(x)\le x$).

Let N($\mathcal{C_n})$ be the set of nilpotent elements of $\mathcal{C}_n$, i.e., $\alpha\in$ N($\mathcal{C_n})$ if and only if there exists positive integer $m$ such that $\alpha^m=0$, where $0$ is the constant map to $1$.
I wonder whether we can characterize the centralizer of any element (different zero) in N($\mathcal{C_n})$. Let $\alpha\in$ N($\mathcal{C_n})$ with $\operatorname{image}(\alpha)=\{1=a_0,a_1,\dots,a_r\}$. Then
$C(\alpha)=\{\beta:\alpha\beta=\beta\alpha\}$.

Comment: Decreasing usually means something else. You might call this "regressive" (suggested [here at MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91141/terminology-for-properties-of-functions))

Comment: Centralizer in $\mathcal{C}_n$  or in $\mathsf{N}(\mathcal{C}_n)$?

Comment: @YCor I try to find in $\mathsf{N}(\mathcal{C}_n)$. Actually, to find the centralizer in $\mathcal{C}_n$ is so interesting.